# all column data in one column separated by special character say -

Tags: mysql

I have table as below

```
create table myTable (id int, 
                  col1 varchar(20),
                  col2 varchar(20),
                  col3 varchar(20),
                  col4 varchar(20),
                  col5 varchar(20),
                  col6 varchar(20),
                  col7 varchar(20),
                  col8 varchar(20),
                  col9 varchar(20)
                 );
```

And have data as

```
insert into myTable values
(1, 'col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6','col7','col8','col9');
```

What I want is output as

```
id +  AllInOne
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 1 + col1-col2-col3-col4-col5-col6-col7-col8-col9
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Any idea how to get this done with smallest query? I know I could do above with use of CONCATENATE. But I would need is some other way. Maybe some pre-defined MySQL function?

### [Data at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7be5b/6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CONCAT_WS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws), that concatenates strings (skipping null ones) with a separator:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT_WS('-', col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9)
FROM your_table
```

Comment: Looks cute... :) Thanks... **Will accept answer after 8 mins**

Answer (score 0):

This will return output exactly like you want:

```
SELECT CONCAT(id,' + ', col1,'-',col2,'-',col3,'-',col4,'-',col5,'-',col6,'-',col7,'-',col8,'-',col9) FROM `your_table` WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: But I don't want to write `'-'` continuously. Also I have this query in my demo link...